# Showing DB List depending on user interaction

Tags: javascript, php, html

Iam currently building a web application heavily based on PHP and MySql.
On one site there are multiple buttons the user can click and depending on what button the user clicks, different MySql Data needs to be shown.
My first thought was to just store all possible outputs into an array but I guess that's performance wise not a good choice since there would be a lot of data that the user might not even want to see.
The other choice is pretty much to load the data AFTER the user clicks on a button and this is what Iam currently trying to work out.

The user clicks on a button and the following function is being executed in Javascript:

```
function requestParticipators(id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "../scripts/request-participators.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            "id"  : id
          },
          success: function(data) {
            if(data.code == 1) {
              $('#userList').html(data.message);
              $("#modalMembers").modal("show");
            }else {
              $("#modalFailed").modal("show");
            }
          },
          error: function(error) {
            $("#modalFailed").modal("show");
          }
        });
      }
```

As you can see if the data is returned successfully I want to show it in a Bootstrap Modal. Before showing it I actually load the data into an empty div called "userList". BUT the data that the "request-participators.php" returns is a huge string since it contains the entire data that the bootstrap modal needs. It currently looks like this:

```php
$stmt->bind_result($db_id, $db_email, $db_vorname, $db_nachname);
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            $output_string .= '<li class="list-group-item px-0">

                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-auto">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col ml-n2">

                        <!-- Title -->
                        <h4 class="mb-1 name">
                            <a href="#">' .$db_vorname .' ' .$db_nachname .'</a>
                        </h4>

                        <!-- Time -->
                        <p class="small mb-0">
                            <span class="text-success">●</span> Online
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">

                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-sm btn-white">
                            Add
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div> <!-- / .row -->

            </li>';
        }
```

The output_string is returned as JSON:

```php
print json_encode(array('message' => $output_string, 'code' => 1));
```

This is the best way that I could come up with... Iam a little concerned about passing back such huge string. Are there any better ways of doing this?
Thank you very much for reading and excuse my bad english >.<

Comment: Have you considered returning JSON data from your PHP code and then processing it client-side - i.e. generating the HTML via JavaScript?

Comment: Iam currently returning it as JSON, I should probably add that to my question :D

Comment: If your PHP is generating HTML then wrapping it inside a JSON object makes no sense...just return the HTML directly and use JavaScript to append it to the page in the place you want it. JSON is more useful for returning raw data, not ready made HTML

Comment: If you want to use JSON, then you should change your code so that PHP just returns the raw data in JSON format, and the JavaScript which receives it does all the work of reading it and creating the HTML to display it. It probably doesn't matter which way round you do it (unless you want to use the PHP as an API for other front ends later, e.g. a mobile app or desktop app), but either way you need to choose a style and stick to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @MaximeLaunois is probably referring to is that your JSON should only contain the actual data pulled from the DB and not any html markup. Something like:

```
..
...
$data=array();
$stmt->bind_result($db_id, $db_email, $db_vorname, $db_nachname);
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            array_push($data, array($db_id, $db_email, $db_vorname, $db_nachname);
        }
...
..
print json_encode($data);
```

And then create the actual markup clientside, using JavaScript.

Comment: Is it better/ faster to generate the actual html using javascript than passing generated the html by PHP?

Comment: You should try and separate backend and frontend functionalities. A single backend job can then be used to supply neutrally formatted data to several applications (frontends), each one taking care of the actual formatting. And, yes: it might even turn out to be faster, as there will be less data transmitted.